# Ruby on rails database: can you create records in your code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wan to create admin user for my application. I want to have admin created at the same time when the application is  created. Like I want a record admin to already be in the database at the very beginning. Is it possible to initialize administrator before actually creating the application, so that when I put the application on heroku and it goes to production mode, the admin is already there with the password and username I specified in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done, using seeds.rb. You can add the initial datas to be loaded in the application after the first deployment.

Your can write the first admin to be created in seeds.rb

```
db/seeds.rb
```

in local you can run as rake db:seed (to populate the initial datas)

If you are using the default PostgreSQL (of heroku), you can run as,

```
heroku pg:reset
heroku run rake db:seed
```

Comment: Thanks. so this is what I should have in seeds.rb: 

User.create(username: "admin", password: "adminpassword", admin: true)    ?

Comment: this is a little weird acturally. What am I supposed to do about the fact that password should be secret, I probably can't just write it in a file?

Comment: You could change the password right away through the UI or put in a random key forcing you to go through the lost password flow.

Comment: You can create a random password for the admin `random_password = (0...8).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join`

Comment: In terms of weird, if this is an app where you care about the security, then you should be using encrypted passwords, for example the bcrypt gem, in which case you can then seed your database with the pre encrypted value rather than the one in the clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seeds.rb` file inside rails to create records what you need and than `heroku run rake db:seed` on heroku

Comment: User.create(username: "admin", password: "adminpassword", admin: true)

Comment: this is how i tried to create user. I first tried in my development app. But when i triedto log in as admin it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I'll do this sometimes - add a `before_create` to the user class.  It can create admins based on whatever I need.

```
before_create :first_user_admin

def first_user_admin
  self.admin = true if User.count == 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to `@Sasidaran`'s answer, you'll definitely be looking at the [`seeds`](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html) functionality of Rails:

```
#db/seeds.rb
Model.find_or_create_by param: "Value"
Model.find_or_create_by param: "Value2"

$ rake db:seed
$ heroku run rake db:seed
```

It's best to think of the `seeds` file as a [batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) -- it just runs through the commands you send to the models etc, allowing you to include any data you need. You can be as complicated or simple as you need.

--

In your case, we don't know your password, or how it's created.

If you're using [`bcrypt-ruby`](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby), you'll want to do something *like* ([`has_secure_password`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password)):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end

#db/seeds.rb
User.crate name: 'david', password: 'mUc3m00RsqyRe', password_confirmation: 'mUc3m00RsqyRe' #-> true

$ rake db:seed
$ heroku run rake db:seed
```

Devise does things differently (I believe). I can update with information about it if you're using it.

Comment: I'm using bycrypt-ruby. But I think something is wrong. I don't really have password_confirmation, so I left that part out. I did User.create username: 'admin', password: 'adminpassword', admin: true

but when I run rake db:seed nothing happens. The terminal just goes to another line. And the user is not created when I run it on localhost. But I run seed with bundle exec rake db:seed, because if I don't I get an error. Do you know hat could be wrong so that my user is not created with seed?

Comment: Hmm - can you post a screenshot of what's happening in the console?